# Using jQuery to control duplicate divs

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have two divs with the same content that have to be shown at different places on the same page. The problem is that when I want to show stuff in the container two I will effect the same divs in container one. Is there a way of making the jQuery treat each container as seperate entities? Do I have to use a jQuery plugin?

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div class="container1">
        <div class="main" style="display:none">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor     incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis      nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.       Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu     fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident,  sunt in     culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </div>
    </div>
    ...
    <div class="container2">
        <div class="main" style="display:none">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor     incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis      nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.       Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu     fugiat n    ulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non            proident,   sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </div>
    <div>

    <div class="button1">Display top main div</div>
    <div class="button2">Display bottom main div</div>
</body>
```

**jQuery**

```
(function($) {
    $(".button1").click(function() {
        $('.main').slideToggle(500);
    });

    $(".button2").click(function() {
        $('.main').slideToggle(500);
    });
})(jQuery);
```

// CAN I USE THIS PLUGIN
(function($) {

```
var methods = {
    init: function(options) {
        return this.each(function() {               
            var $this = $(this);       

        });
    }
};

$.fn.plugin = function(method) {
    if (methods[method]) {
        return methods[method].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
    } else if (typeof method === 'object' || !method) {
        return methods.init.apply(this, arguments);
    } else {
        $.error('Method ' + method + ' does not exist on jQuery.plugin');
    }
};
```

})(jQuery);

Comment: Is there some reason why you can't give them unique ids (in addition to the shared class)? Also why are you selecting your "button" divs based on what appears to be unique class names rather than ids?

Comment: I have to give them classes. There is a lot more code than this and this is just an example. I am duplicating a lot of code but need to treat them as individual entities if u know what I mean :)

Comment: Please don't change your question after people have answered. I wrote you an answer for your original html where they really were duplicate divs because they had containers with the same class, and upon posting it found that while I was typing you'd updated the question so now the containers have distinct classes (which is what ids are for).

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick:

```
(function($) {

    $(".button1").click(function() {
        $('.container1 .main').slideToggle(500);
    });

    $(".button2").click(function() {
        $('.container2 .main').slideToggle(500);
    });

})(jQuery);
```

You would have to rename the top container's class to .container1 though. But I assume that is the plan since you refer to it as `container one` in your description.

Comment: that is a good way of doing it but I have a lot of jquery and I dont want to change it all - please see amendment to original question.

Comment: Unfortunatly, you current jQuery code can't do anything else but "slide toggle **all** elements that contain the class `.main`". Without updating your code, you're never going to be able to differentiate between your divs.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you think you need a plugin for this - a plugin isn't going to do anything you can't do directly, though it may make it much more convenient if you use it a lot.

For your *original* question where both containers had the same class you can do it like this:

```
(function($) {

    var $mainDivs = $(".container2 .main");

    $(".button1").click(function() {
        $mainDivs.eq(0).slideToggle(500);
    });

    $(".button2").click(function() {
        mainDivs.eq(1).slideToggle(500);
    });

})(jQuery);
```

Where the selector `$(".container2 .main");` gives you a jQuery object containing both ".main" divs and the [`.eq()` method](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) lets you perform operations on the one at the specified zero-based index.

Now that you've edited your markup to give them different classes you can simply say:

```
    $(".button1").click(function() {
        $(".container1 .main").slideToggle(500);
    });

    $(".button2").click(function() {
        $(".container2 .main").slideToggle(500);
    });
```

But it would be much better to give them unique ids than unique classes. You can give them an id attribute *and* a class.

Comment: that is a good way of doing it but I have a lot of jquery and I dont want to change it all - please see amendment to original question.

Comment: I don't understand. I've told you how to do it for both your original and your amended html markup. What am I missing?

Answer (score -1):

You could rename the first container in "container1"

Comment: Hey i'm here to help you....if i see two divs classes with the same name, and your problem is to change only one div, i can think your problem is the name!!!!